# Regular expression for check number and +

Tags: javascript, regex

Sorry for very useless question!

I need regular expression for check this type of string

+7

i was try .replace(/^+[0-9][^\d]/g, '') but it give me all another type of math symbols, i need 
First symbol + 
Second one number 1 - 9

Comment: Please share the relevant code. Are you trying to only keep the first `+` and a digit in the string? Try `.replace(/^(\+\d).*/, '$1')`

Comment: The only problem in your regular expression is that you should escape the '+'' like that :  `/^\+[0-9][^\d]/g`  and then it work fine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes i trying do +7 checker, 

sorry replace(/^+[0-9][^\d]/g, '')

Comment: So, you say you need to validate a string starting with `+` and then having any one digit? `s.test(/^\+[1-9]$/)` might work.

Comment: value.replace(/\+\d+/gm)  - this variant not working! I need only first 
symbol +
 and  after one number form 1 to 9 only

Comment: @SebastianLagua As I already asked, please share your code. It is not clear what you are doing. And explain in details: 1) what string comes in, 2) what output you need to get.

Answer (score 0):

your regex needs to be

```
^\+[0-9][^\d]
```

if you want to match all numbers starting with + you can use

```
/\+\d+/g
```

> Note this would match +73ab and return +73

If you want just numbers you can use

```
/\b\+\d+\b/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Plus `+` is a special character used in regular expressions to indicate one or more occurrences of the expression before it. That's why it does not work in your example. You should escape it with `\`.

1. If you want to get all numbers prefixed by plus in multiline text, you can use:

   `/\+\d+/gm`

For Example:

```js
var numbers = 'skdlfjlk +7fsd \r\nsd;flk+123'.match(/\+\d+/gm);
console.log(numbers); // => ["+7", "+123"]
```

2. If by "number" you actually meaning digit from `1` to `9`, and you are interested only in first occurrence in the string, you can use:

   `/\+[1-9]/m`
3. If, in addition, you need it to be the beginning of the string, you can use just:

   `/^\+[1-9]/`